# Facebook wall post without showing feed dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I want to post on user's wall after successful login but i dont want to show the feed dialog popup to ask permission to publish. I want to publish silently. I had seen FB.api provides one way to post so but it does not render html tag like anchor tag and all. here is my code

```
   function postToFeed(){
            // calling the API ...              
            var obj = {
                method: 'feed',
                redirect_uri: 'url to website',
                link: 'link to website',
                picture: 'live picture url',
                name: "",
                caption: "",
                description:""
            };

            function callback(response) {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }
```

I have followed [Facebook Developers code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: You can use facebook like functionality to avoid permission dialog box.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal thanx for the suggestion I found a better solution 
http://daipratt.co.uk/using-fb-api-to-make-a-full-post-to-a-users-wall/comment-page-1/#comment-122352

Comment: here's a much more detailed article: http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/406-publish-actions-with-facebook-javascript-sdk

Comment: @ThePCWizard nice link.. Thanx man !!!!